# Customer account EDT without referential integrity

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I maintain a table of some specific configuration informations for customers.

The identifier of this table is the customer account, the `CustAccount` EDT.

Now I face a problem : this configuration information must sometimes be defined **before** the customer is created.

Is there a way to create a non-restrictive EDT, which will be related to `CustAccount` (we can select the value among existing accounts), but which allows other values than existing accounts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You want to look at examples in the AOT that use the base enum `TableGroupAll`. For your case, you'd probably create a new EDT called `TableAll` (Which exists in AX2012).

Look at how `\Data Dictionary\Tables\AssetDisposalParameters` works or anything that uses `\Data Dictionary\Base Enums\TableGroupAll`.

Essentially it's like a 2-field key, where you'd have `Table`+`CustAccount` connect to the `CustTable`, but `All` would just be a blank `CustAccount`.

[image]

**EDIT:** [Here is an AX 2009 XPO example that you can quickly see working well.](http://pastebin.com/raw/6CXtUiWF)

Also, don't do what the other poster suggested. Even in AX 2012 you'd want to do something similar to what I suggested unless you have some very special requirements.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. You suggest to create a new base enum (MyPrefix)TableAll, which will allow to create a new kind of relation between EDT and table, then create a new EDT using this kind of relation ?

Comment: You'll want to use a new `EDT` instead of `CustAccount` as that has a relation setup directly on it. I've updated my post with an `XPO` that shows exactly how to do it. The way I suggest is the preferred way to accomplish what you want generally.

Comment: Ok your example works. Either I work on a known Customer and select the value "Table", either I need a non-existing code (at the moment) and I will select the value "All". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `IgnoreEDTRelation` to `yes`. Now you can use this EDT without foreign key constraint.
For the lookup part... you need to overwrite a method `lookup` on the field of a `datasource` on your `form`.

```
public void lookup(FormControl _formControl, str _filterStr)
{
    Query query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;

    SysTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(CustTable), _formControl); 

    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, CustGroup)); 

    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTable));

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();

    //super(_formControl, _filterStr);
}
```

[How to: Add a Lookup Form to a Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185372.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
This link shows how to add a custom lookup to a control. But it is more "clean" to overwrite datasource field method so that if you have more than one control on the form using this field all will have this lookup.

Comment: Thanks but it seems that IgnoreEDTRelation was created in AX2012